# Question 7.1 of Introduction to analytic number theory ( Apostol)

Tags: number-theory

I am self studying number theory from Tom M Apostol and I couldn't think about how to solve this particular problem.

> let h and k are given positive integers (h, k) =1 and A(h, k) = { h+kx : x=0,1,2,... } .

> Without assuming dirichlet theorem prove that for every integer $n\geq 1$ , A(h, k) contains infinitely many  numbers relatively prime to n.

Attempt:  I assumed that let there exist only finitely many terms( say m)in A(h, k)  relatively prime to n in hope of finding contradiction.

So, for other integers in A(h, k) which are infinitely many  say $l_i$(n,  $l_i$) =d, d>1 . Intutively, one can say that n would be very large only so that's not true for every n .
But I am not able to prove it rigorously.

Can you please prove it rigorously or give an alternative approach which is straightforward.

Thanks!!

Comment: Bezout is your friend.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe It's not at all clear how you intend this to be solved following that remark.